# c# looping through distinct values in datatable

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linq

i have a datatable:

```
+----------+--------+
| Rep Name | Volume |
+----------+--------+
| Alex     |      9 |
| Alex     |      1 |
| Alex     |      3 |
| Liza     |     24 |
| Liza     |     17 |
| Pam      |      0 |
| Pam      |      6 |
+----------+--------+
```

i am sending ONE email for every UNIQUE person in `REP NAME`

example:

```
Hi Alex, Today your volume was 9, and 1, and 3.
```

next email:

```
Hi Liza, Today your valume was 24, and 17.
```

i would like to know the easiest way to loop through the datatable on unique values of `REPNAME`

something like:

```
 var DistinctList = datatable123.Select(x=> x.repname).Distinct();
```

and then i would loop through DistinctList ?

Comment: @Wesley var DistinctList = datatable123.Select(x=> x.repname).Distinct();

Comment: @Wesley also this i have tried var list = from x in datatable123
           group x by x.repname into g
           select g;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `GroupBy` for this task.

Update: I've rewritten the code so you can now use it with your `DataTable`.

```
var list = from x in datatable123.AsEnumerable()
           group x by (string) x["repname"] into g
           select g;

foreach (var x in list)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Hi {0}, Today your volume was {1}.", x.Key,
      String.Join(", and ", x.Select(p => p["volume"])));
}
```

Comment: Error 1 Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Data.DataTable'.  'GroupBy' not found.

Comment: thanks so much for your hel pbut i guess we cant do groupbby on datatable?

Comment: @I__ You need to query the persons into an object list, then you will be able to call groupby on it.

Comment: @BalazsTihanyi: no you don't, just add `.ToEnumerable()` after `datatable123`

Comment: @DStanley Yeah, thanks for the tip. It's been a long time since I've used datatables...